The platform image 'MicrosoftWindowsServer:WindowsServer:2019-Datacenter:17763.xx' is deprecated. (Code: ImageVersionDeprecated, Target: imageReferenc
I am writing bicep code that aims to script out an existing VM and recreate using bicep. It creates an Os disk, however the referenced Os disk is now deprecated. My question is this, how can I resolve the issue ?
param disks_mydeltavm001_osdisk_name string = 'mydeltavm001-osdisk'
param diskEncryptionSets_des_delta_dev_001_externalid string = '/subscriptions/xxx/resourceGroups/my-rg/providers/Microsoft.Compute/diskEncryptionSets/des-delta-dev-001'

    resource disks_mydeltavm001_osdisk_name_resource 'Microsoft.Compute/disks@2023-01-02' = {
      name: disks_mydeltavm001_osdisk_name
      location: 'uksouth'
      sku: {
        name: 'Standard_LRS'
        tier: 'Standard'
      }
      properties: {
        osType: 'Windows'
        hyperVGeneration: 'V1'
        supportsHibernation: true
        supportedCapabilities: {
          acceleratedNetwork: true
          architecture: 'x64'
        }
        creationData: {
          createOption: 'FromImage'
          imageReference: {
            id: '/Subscriptions/xxx/Providers/Microsoft.Compute/Locations/uksouth/Publishers/MicrosoftWindowsServer/ArtifactTypes/VMImage/Offers/WindowsServer/Skus/2019-Datacenter/Versions/17763.3650.221105'
          }
        }
        diskSizeGB: 128
        diskIOPSReadWrite: 500
        diskMBpsReadWrite: 60
        encryption: {
          type: 'EncryptionAtRestWithCustomerKey'
          diskEncryptionSetId: diskEncryptionSets_des_delta_dev_001_externalid
        }
        networkAccessPolicy: 'DenyAll'
        publicNetworkAccess: 'Disabled'
        diskState: 'Attached'
      }
    }

I have tried to be smart by changing the image Id tag to latest
    `id: '/Subscriptions/xx/Providers/Microsoft.Compute/Locations/uksouth/Publishers/MicrosoftWindowsServer/ArtifactTypes/VMImage/Offers/WindowsServer/Skus/2019-Datacenter/Versions/latest'`

I am not convinced it works as when the VM builds, it doesnt get the OS name, and I do not know if that VM image exists in the location stated above, how can I navigate to see the image and perhaps create a new one ?

can't you use a different version ?

How do I reference this ? It appears to be a custom image being used here.

in the imageReference in your bicep, you should be able to change the version / or using latest

Have you tried updating this datacenter version to 2022-Datacenter. @learner
